# Event for when file has loaded

Tags: javascript, dom

The code below runs on a page:

```
(function() {
  function asyncLoad() {
    var urls = ["https://something.com/script.js"];
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
      var s = document.createElement('script');
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.async = true;
      s.src = urls[i];
      var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    }
  }
  window.attachEvent ? window.attachEvent('onload', asyncLoad) : window.addEventListener('load', asyncLoad, false);
})();
//]]>
```

I need an event listener that fires when this file is available in the DOM.

I need to utilize variables from this script.

I need to know when `https://something.com/script.js` has been loaded and if it is not I would like a backup to fire. This can happen if the file hasn't loaded within a designated period of time.

Alternatively I could use an event for when a variable is available from the script.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script elements support the load event, so you should set the listener on the script element before inserting it in the DOM, e.g.

```
  s.src = urls[i];

  s.onload = asyncLoad; // add load listener

  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
```

If you want to know if it arrived successfuly or not, use XMLHttpRequest to get the content, then assign it to the script element's *text* property. That way you can know if the script was retreived, set a timeout in case of failure and take corrective action and not lock the browser in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

If in your `script.js` has a function for example: `function a()` then you can catch when it available like this

```
var checkScript = function(){
   if (typeof a  === "function"){
      //fire event
   }else{
      setTimeout(checkScript, 1000);
   }
}
checkScript ();
```

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756382/bookmarklet-wait-until-javascript-is-loaded http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955770/dynamically-include-javascript-and-wait